# Qt Creator Can't use const char*

Tags: c++, c, qt

I was just testing with qt creator and seem to like it as the gui of my C++. Working around with some stuff  and it seems that I can't use const char*!

If I add a function:

header

```
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    const char* nativeStr(QString str1);
```

cpp

```
const char* nativeStr(QString str1){
    QByteArray ba = str1.toLocal8Bit();
    return (const char*)ba.data();
}
```

I get the error (when debugging):

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * -_thiscall MainWindow::nativeStr(class QString)" 9?nativeStr @MainWindow@@QAEPBDVQString@@@z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

File not found: mainwindow.obj
```

Help? I have no idea and I've only used win32 C++ before.

I've also tried:
build->clean all
build->run qmake

Comment: try including the cpp file in your project. it's not being compiler, or its object code is not being linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `MainWindow::` part of the function name:

```
const char* MainWindow::nativeStr(QString str1){
    QByteArray ba = str1.toLocal8Bit();
    return (const char*)ba.data();
}
```

Comment: thanks I forgot about the class... ugh I'm such a noob sometimes.